# iframe won't show up unless domain has www

Tags: iframe, web, x-frame-options

I have a site with an iframe. The iframe shows up if the address url is www.mysite.com, but not if I use mysite.com.  The iframe location is www.mysite.com/thepage.html

The JS error I get is.

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: the site page does not permit
>   cross-origin framing.

On my server (webfaction) I have the site setup to recognize both with and without the www -- a control panel item on webfaction.

How do I get mysite.com to show the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the webmaster of the domain has set XSS protection. So to load a XSS protected site with javascript is simply can't be done.

**Update:** XSS only allow access to data if both frames (iframe/parent frame) they are on the same protocol, have the exact domain name (mysite.com == mysite.com, but www.mysite.com != mysite.com they are considered different) and both of frames running on the same port. But though, you can ive it a try by placing document.domain on all pages so it allows communication even on different subdomains.

Comment: It's from the same domain but without the www.